# Order by multiple column is should be in squence

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Is Order by multiple columns is **Sequential** type or **Non sequential**..?

```
skill_id   student_id 
   1          23
   2          24
   5          26
   3          20
   7          29
```

What i meant to ask you is i am trying to order by 2 columns they are like

```
order by skill_id DESC,
student_id ASC
```

In **1st** Query i wrote like mentioned above

In **2nd** Query i wrote like `order by student_id ASC,skill_id DESC`

Is Both results the same thing or different if diff Can you expalin me how..?

Comment: Yes, order of columns in ORDER BY clause matters.

Comment: Take some cups and plates out of a cupboard. Arrange them by size, shape, and colour. Now arrange them by colour, shape, and size. Are they in the same order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are different.
The order of the columns is critical in the order by clause.
In your specific example there is actually no meaning to the second column, only the first one, since there are no duplicate values in any column in your sample data.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
order by skill_id DESC,
student_id ASC


skill_id    student_id
7           29
5           26
3           20
2           24
1           23

SELECT *
FROM table 
order by student_id ASC, skill_id DESC

skill_id    student_id
3           20
1           23
2           24
5           26
7           29
```

If there where duplicate values in one column, then the second column in the order by would control how to order the second column.
Here are the same queries with a different sample data:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T 
order by skill_id DESC,
student_id ASC


skill_id    student_id
7           9
7           29
5           6
5           26
3           0
3           20
2           2
2           24
1           3
1           23

SELECT *
FROM @T 
order by student_id ASC, skill_id DESC


skill_id    student_id
3           0
2           2
1           3
5           6
7           9
3           20
1           23
2           24
5           26
7           29
```

Answer (score 2):

They're different. It first orders the results by the first column. Then within groups that have the same value of the first column, it orders by the second column. And so on for each column.

If you don't have any duplicates of the first column, the remaining columns in `ORDER BY` are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The query simply read the first condition in ORDER BY:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY skill_id DESC,
student_id ASC
```